# Get list of all fields in all salesforce objects

Tags: salesforce

I have a specific field that I am trying to find. The salesforce instance I am in has hundreds of tables/objects so I can't look through them manually.

I also only have read only access, so I can't run an APEX script or create objects. I am using an API to access the database, and store the data outside of salesforce.

What I need is to find the object/table that this field is stored in so I can write an SOQL query to get the field's values. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Easiest way is with [Workbench](https://workbench.developerforce.com/login.php).

Comment: Thanks, looks like I can use SOSL to find values within fields which is helpful as well. Would you know how to search for field names in the workbench?

Comment: Workbench has a metadata explorer that will show you all the fields on an object.